Vulkan - Fragment shader doesn't seem to output anything to swapchain image
I started building a little renderer to try out Vulkan (coming from OpenGL). I started by a good old triangle but the fragment shader doesn't want to output anything. My output image (coming directly from the swapchain) stays filled with the clear color. I'm using Vulkan 1.3 for dynamic rendering.
Using RenderDoc, I can see that the vertex shader works, but the output stays desperately empty. Here are some parts of my capture (if that can help) :
Rasterizer tab of my graphics pipeline during the vkCmdDraw call
Blend and depth state
Capture and API inspector
I try to disable rasterizer discard, disable face culling. I also try to tweak the blend state in all way possible, but nothing changed.
Here is my mainloop (if that can help) :
VkRenderingAttachmentInfo renderingAttachmentInfos {};
renderingAttachmentInfos.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_ATTACHMENT_INFO;
renderingAttachmentInfos.clearValue.color = {{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.f}};
renderingAttachmentInfos.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
renderingAttachmentInfos.imageView = context.getSwapchain()->getImageViews()[imageIndex];
renderingAttachmentInfos.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
renderingAttachmentInfos.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
renderingAttachmentInfos.resolveMode = VK_RESOLVE_MODE_NONE;
renderingAttachmentInfos.resolveImageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
renderingAttachmentInfos.resolveImageView = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

VkRenderingInfo renderingInfos {};
renderingInfos.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDERING_INFO;
renderingInfos.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
renderingInfos.pColorAttachments = &renderingAttachmentInfos;
renderingInfos.renderArea.offset = {0, 0};
renderingInfos.renderArea.extent = context.getSwapchain()->getExtent();
renderingInfos.layerCount = 1;
renderingInfos.viewMask = 0;

VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfos {};
beginInfos.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
beginInfos.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
beginInfos.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;
(void)vkBeginCommandBuffer(graphicsCommandBuffer, &beginInfos);

VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier {};
imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
imageMemoryBarrier.image = context.getSwapchain()->getImages()[imageIndex];
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    graphicsCommandBuffer,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &imageMemoryBarrier
);

vkCmdBeginRendering(graphicsCommandBuffer, &renderingInfos);

vkCmdBindPipeline(graphicsCommandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipeline.getPipeline());

VkViewport viewport {};
viewport.x = 0.f;
viewport.y = 0.f;
viewport.width = context.getSwapchain()->getExtent().width;
viewport.height = context.getSwapchain()->getExtent().height;
viewport.minDepth = 0.f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.f;
vkCmdSetViewport(graphicsCommandBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);

VkRect2D scissor {};
scissor.offset = {0, 0};
scissor.extent = context.getSwapchain()->getExtent();
vkCmdSetScissor(graphicsCommandBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);

VkBuffer buffer {vertexBuffer.getBuffer()};
VkDeviceSize offset {vertexBufferView.getInfos().offset};
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(graphicsCommandBuffer, 0, 1, &buffer, &offset);

vkCmdDraw(graphicsCommandBuffer, vertices.size() / 5, vertices.size() / 15, 0, 0);

vkCmdEndRendering(graphicsCommandBuffer);

imageMemoryBarrier = {};
imageMemoryBarrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
imageMemoryBarrier.image = context.getSwapchain()->getImages()[imageIndex];
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
    graphicsCommandBuffer,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &imageMemoryBarrier
);

(void)vkEndCommandBuffer(graphicsCommandBuffer);


VkSubmitInfo submitInfos {};
VkPipelineStageFlags dstStageMask {VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT};
submitInfos.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submitInfos.commandBufferCount = 1;
submitInfos.pCommandBuffers = &graphicsCommandBuffer;
submitInfos.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfos.pWaitSemaphores = &imageReadySemaphore;
submitInfos.pWaitDstStageMask = &dstStageMask;
submitInfos.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfos.pSignalSemaphores = &imageDrawnSemaphore;
(void)vkQueueSubmit(context.getDevice()->getQueue(se::renderer::vulkan::QueueType::eGraphics), 1, &submitInfos, previousFrameReadyFence);

VkSwapchainKHR swapchain {context.getSwapchain()->getSwapChain()};
VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfos {};
presentInfos.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
presentInfos.swapchainCount = 1;
presentInfos.pSwapchains = &swapchain;
presentInfos.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;
presentInfos.pResults = nullptr;
presentInfos.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
presentInfos.pWaitSemaphores = &imageDrawnSemaphore;
(void)vkQueuePresentKHR(context.getDevice()->getQueue(se::renderer::vulkan::QueueType::ePresent), &presentInfos);

After a bit more testing, the only place where my code works is with an Nvidia GPU (rtx 4060 Mobile) on Arch with the proprietary driver

Usual first check - any errors in validation layers?

@solidpixel I get an error the first time I transition each swapchain image to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL because the image is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED instead of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR. But in RenderDoc, the image has the right layout (color attachment). It seems that AMD driver (on Arch) allow this operation

@solidpixel I made the transition (so no more error in validation layers) but it's still not working

The problem was that I was not passing VkPipelineRenderingCreateInfo object in the pNext chain of VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo
